# Django Assigning or saving value to Foreign Key field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

can any one help me with assigning value to a foreign key field.
Im trying to create user profile where user can add there countries.
when creating the models, from django admin page there is no problem adding countries
im only having an error in the front end side when adding country select option
and I got an error value

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "{'countries': 1}": "RegsModel.nationality" must be a "Country" instance.
```

please see my omitted  code.

**models.py**

```
class RegsModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=64)
    nationality = models.ForeignKey(Country,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Employee_ID

class Country(models.Models):
    countries = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=64)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.countries
```

**forms.py**

```
class RegsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RegsModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegsForm(request.POST)
        if RegsFrom.is_valid()
            form.save(commit=False)
            form.nationality = request.POST['nationality']
    
    else:
        form = RegsForm(request.POST)

    return request('register', views.register, name='register',{'form':form})
```

**register.html**

```
<form method='POST'>
   {{form.as_p}}
   <button type='submit'>add</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass Country `instance` in nationality `field` instead of simple value.

**views.py:**

```
    def register(request):
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = RegsForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid()
                obj = form.save(commit=False)
                country_inst = Country.objects.get(countries = request.POST['nationality'])  # Pass country(e.g. 'India') value instead of dict..
                obj.nationality = country_inst
                obj.save()
        
        else:
            form = RegsForm(request.POST)
    
        return request('register', views.register, name='register',{'form':form})
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you do `form.nationality = request.POST['nationality']` you can just do  `form.save()` and it will create the object for you because you already add the field to the form by the `fields = '__all__'` in your form

```
class RegsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = RegsModel
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0):

To save value in forignkey just give the current object to the forignkey and rest forignkey will pickup its value.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you please clarify your answer? Perhaps with an example?